# Learning Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, portlet, suitescript

I am starting to learn Netsuite, since that is required for our New project.
I am completely new to it. Currently I am working on PHP.

As suggested by my manager I created the developer account on it. But I have no Idea about It. So if someone can spare to answer my below questions than I will be very greatful.

1. Do i need to learn JavaScript for that?
2. Is here any other technology that will be needed ?
3. Are there any free webresources that can give me the insight on this?
4. How long will it take to learn netsuite once My javascript is done?

Thanks in advance.
Glad

Comment: If you hope to do any deep customization, you are going to need JavaScript. The documentation for NetSuite is rather lacking, but a good start would be NetSuite's Help Center. The classes are actually really helpful, but they're not cheap, and I suspect they're the reason why their documentation is not great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Netsuite family !! 
You may want to explore some basic about Netsuite. I would recommend to explore the NS help center as you gotten with a DEV account. Start with simple things and then move on to advance i.e APIs and integration level.

Responding to your quires :

> (1) Do i need to learn JavaScript for that?

As you have mentioned you're coding ground is PHP, I guess you already have minimum expose to javascript and some functional programming. You dont need to be an expert to startup with. If you're completely noob to coding then you may want to explore some baics [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) to start with javascript.

> (2) Is here any other technology that will be needed ?

I would say it much depends on your business needs. Netsuite supports both Rest & SOAP based access. For Rest access you need to know javascript as the API's are completely build upon on Suitescripts (NS dependent javascript) and for SOAP based access you can use either JAVA,.NET or PHP.

> (3) Are there any free webresources that can give me the insight on this?

The very obvious place is the NS help center where you can explore more in details.You also may request for a membership in NS user group [here](https://usergroup.netsuite.com).

> (4) How long will it take to learn netsuite once My javascript is done?

Netsuite is not only limited to javascript or any specific programming. There are alot of things you need to lean apart from javascript. Remeber Learning never exhausts the mind !! ;)

Cheers!
Happy Learning.. :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes you'll need Javascript.  The entire API of NetSuite is written in Javascript.  If you get the basics of if statements, for loops and understand how objects and functions work, its a pretty good foundation to start with.
2. That really depends on what you want to achieve.  NetSuite's API will allow you to integrate to other platforms, APIs etc using a range of different things.  This one is more a "what do you want" type question.
3. The UserGroup for NetSuite is a good place to start.  That is free.  The documentation help has examples which will get you started.  I'd start small and then go from there.  Ie. How do I get a field value?  Read, Develop, Test.  Then move on to "How do I set a value" Read, Develop, Test etc etc.  You'll learn more and you'll be a better developer for it.
4. I've been coding in NetSuite for over 7 years for a range of clients.  Fair to say you never "learn" NetSuite.  It continues to evolve and you evolve with it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "The entire API of NetSuite is written in Javascript." - To be pedantic, that only applies to one of NetSuite's APIs (namely, SuiteScript). I use SuiteTalk, the SOAP web service API, which can be used in Java, C#, C++ and other languages. Which API you should use depends on what you want to do with NetSuite.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you need only basic information about javascript. We are using here suitescript language. you are already familier with programming so it will not be difficult for you.
2. For integration purpose you may be need.
3. May be.
4. It will take hardly 1 month. First you learn manual , later you start coding. It will helpful for you.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the answers to your fairly vague questions:

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Probably
4. 1 month - 10 years

Should you require more granular answers please provide me with further details.